# È corretta l'espressione "perpetrare una specie" anziché "perpetuare una specie"?

Tags: meaning, difference, single-words

Leggendo i commenti dei lettori ad un [fumetto pubblicato da Tom's Hardware](https://comics.tomshw.it/197/l-esperimento-31) ho trovato una discussione sui verbi "perpetrare" e "perpetuare".

Il fumetto in questione parla di una razza aliena che corre il rischio di estinguersi, e che cerca di trovare un modo per evitarlo. Nell'ultima vignetta il fumettista ha usato l'espressione "perpetrare la specie", e un lettore gli ha fatto notare che si tratta di un errore, perché l'espressione corretta è "perpetuare la specie". L'autore si è scusato e ha corretto la tavola.

Un altro lettore, però, ha detto che secondo lui si possono usare entrambi i termini. Il primo allora ha risposto:

> No, "perpetrare" significa compiere un'azione illecita, per esempio si perpetra un delitto. "Perpetuare", invece, significa rendere perpetuo, eterno. Nel contesto di questa vignetta si può usare solo "perpetuare".

Al che il secondo ha risposto a sua volta:

> perpetrare significa portare avanti o compiere qualcosa anche in senso figurato. Quindi si può usare per perpetrare un reato, perpetrare la specie, perpetrare un'azione ecc. E' molto usato nel lessico giudiziario ma non ne è di esclusivo uso. P. es. un'azione militare audace alla rambo può essere perpetrata. Può essere usato anche in zoologia per indicare proprio l'azione di allungare la vita ad una specie animale nel caso di un intervento esterno p. es. (guarda caso) da parte di un ricercatore
>
> perpetuare ha significato nel senso di ripetere qualcosa o portarla avanti anche in senso figurato. Quindi può essere usato per perpetuare un reato (nel senso di ripeterlo più volte), perpetuare la specie (nel senso figurato o materiale di portarla avanti), perpetuare un'azione (anche qui nel senso di ripeterla) ecc.
>
> sono differenze minime che nel caso in specie (assicurare il prosieguo della specie aliena) non hanno importanza per cui possono essere utilizzati entrambi
>
> L'italiano è complicato, pieno di sfumature ed eccezioni

Questa risposta mi lascia davvero perplesso. Mi verrebbe da dire che ha ragione il primo lettore: si perpetra un reato e si perpetua una specie, e non si può dire "perpetrare una specie". Anche l'esempio della zoologia, in cui indicherebbe l'azione di allungare la vita ad un animale, mi sembra completamente sbagliato. E "perpetuare un reato" nel senso di "ripeterlo più volte" mi sembra come minimo un'interpretazione molto forzata, perché "perpetuo" indica un singolo evento che non termina, mentre qui si tratterebbe di una ripetizione di eventi, che non è la stessa cosa. E non mi sembrano affatto "differenze minime" o "sfumature".

Sui vocabolari che ho consultato (per "perpetrare": [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/perpetrare/), [Wikizionario](https://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/perpetrare), [Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/perpetrare.shtml), [Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=perpetrare), [Repubblica](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/P/perpetrare.php)) non ho trovato nulla che supportasse anche solo in minima parte la tesi di questo secondo lettore. Ma visto che sembra molto convinto del fatto suo, vorrei sentire altri pareri.

È possibile usare i verbi "perpetrare" e "perpetuare" nel senso indicato da questo lettore?

Comment: Senza fonti a favore dell'uso “figurato” di perpetrare, direi che la risposta è no. Tra l'altro “perpetuare” come “ripetere” mi sembra davvero molto forzato. Benvenuto!

Comment: Con una ricerca Google di `"perpetrare una specie"` trovo solo quattro casi: https://www.google.it/#q=%22perpetrare+una+specie%22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non sono d'accordo con questo utente. Direi che i due verbi "perpetrare" e "perpetuare" sono completamente diversi come significato, tanto quanto lo sono i loro sinonimi (approssimativi) "fare" e "continuare". Nel caso in cui la somiglianza avesse portato l'utente a pensare che abbiano un'etimologia comune (e quindi si possano, in qualche modo, considerare due forme per la stessa parola), da una breve ricerca mi sembra che non sia così: tolto il prefisso *per*, che in entrambi i casi sembra un intensificativo,

- **perpetrare** viene da *patro*, che significa "eseguire", "compiere" e sembra essere etimologicamente legato a "padre", nel senso di colui che genera;
- **perpetuare** viene da *peto*, che significa "procedere verso" e fa probabilmente un riferimento figurato all'eterno procedere del tempo.

Comment: Senza entrare nel merito, "perpetrare la specie aliena" ha un suo valore letterario. Specialmente se gli alieni sono cattivi invasori. Può essere una licenza :)